# Content of FSIMAGE and EDIT files in Hadoop command error

Tags: java, hadoop, hdfs

I am using Hadoop 2.2.0 version. I want to see the content of "FSIMAGE" and "EDITS" files. i used following command:

> bin/hdfs oiv -i fsimage -o fsimage.txt
>
> bin/hdfs oev -i edits -o edits.xml

I came to know about these commands from [Aapche hadoop site documentation](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsImageViewer.html). I ran sample word count program and after this tried above command and got this:-

```
rushi@ubuntu:/usr/local/hadoop$ bin/hdfs oiv -i fsimage -o fsimage.xml -p XML
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.offlineImageViewer.OfflineImageViewer.go(OfflineImageViewer.java:140)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.offlineImageViewer.OfflineImageViewer.main(OfflineImageViewer.java:260)
```

"fsimage.xml" file created but it is EMPTY.

What may be the problem or how can i see the content of these files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It like your current working direcotry is /usr/local/hadoop.  I suspect the file fsimage does not exist in the direcotry and the oiv class is failing to find it.

```
> [root@hdm1 current]# hdfs oiv -i fsimage -o /tmp/a Exception in thread
> "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.offlineImageViewer.OfflineImageViewer.go(OfflineImageViewer.java:140)
>   at
> org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.tools.offlineImageViewer.OfflineImageViewer.main(OfflineImageViewer.java:260)
```

Example using the full path to FSIMAGE file

```
>     [root@hdm1 current]# hdfs oiv -i /data/nn/dfs/name/current/fsimage_0000000000000002415 -o
> /tmp/fsimage.txt
>     [root@hdm1 current]#
```